# suplied for foreach() with F3 framework and mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, foreach, fat-free-framework

I'have to work with F3 framework and MongoDb. I'm working in local an try to get data from my mongo Data base.

I got a db called 'wtfay' and  a collection called 'students'. When I try find() method to get all students my navigator return : 'Internal Server error. Supplied for foreach()'. This foreach is in the 'mapper.php' line 87 , from the framework in the factory function.

```
protected function factory($row) {
    $mapper=clone($this);
    $mapper->reset();
    foreach ($row as $key=>$val)
        $mapper->document[$key]=$val;
    $mapper->query=array(clone($mapper));
    if (isset($mapper->trigger['load']))
        \Base::instance()->call($mapper->trigger['load'],$mapper);
    return $mapper;
}
```

To connect to the DB I create a studentsModel

```
namespace APP\MODELS;

class StudentsModel extends \DB\Mongo\Mapper {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( new \DB\Mongo(new \MongoClient ('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'), 'wtfay'), 'students' );
    }
}
```

In the controller to get all students I did this :

```
public function get($f3, $params) {
    $this->_data = $this->_studentsModel->find();           
}
```

Thank's for your request !

ADR Dra

Comment: Haven't tried the approach to extend the Mongo Mapper yet, but are you 100% sure you DB even returns any data? Beside that, you don't have to create the MongoClient object manually. F3 does that for you, if you just pass the DSN string.

Comment: When I use my terminal with mongo I execute : db.students.find() and Mongo give me the JSON.